# run sample test case of uiveri5 show error "Reference Error: describe is not defined"

Tags: uiveri5

I installed the @ui5/uiveri5 globally correctly.  I download the ui-uiveri5 repository, then I go to directory of sample\apiTesting, and run the command
`uiveri5 APITesting.spec`

it report following error:

```
C:\src\open\ui5-uiveri5\sample\apiTesting\APITesting.spec.js:2
describe('APITesting', function() {
^
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
```

Please guide me on how to solve this issue. ( It report the same issue after I install the jasmine-node, mocha globally).

Answer (score 0):

No need to install jasmine or mocha, just install uiveri5 globally with `npm install @ui5/uiveri5 -g`. Can you please try again, I merged a fix for another small issue. And with it, this sample starts fine.